# Expected value of two dependent Bernoulli random variables.

Tags: probability, expectation

I'm in the process of finding $E(XY)$ where X and Y are non-independent Bernoulli random variables with both of them with probability of $\frac{n}{N}$

I understand that $E(XY)=\Sigma\Sigma x_{i}y_{i}P(X,Y)$ and this got me to the point where I can write:
$E(XY)=P(X=1,Y=1)\cdot1+P(X=1,Y=0)\cdot0+P(X=0,Y=1)\cdot0+P(X=0,Y=0)\cdot0$
$=P(X=1,Y=1)$

But Im very lost here.
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are both Bernoulli random variable with same probability of success. So $P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=p$
Nothing much is given to be honest.

Comment: You have correctly identified $\mathsf E(XY)=\mathsf P(X=1,Y=1)$.  We *cannot* proceed because we do not know what this joint probability may be. Your post has specified that the variables are *not* independent yet *not* indicated what dependency they do have.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. It's just equal to the probability that both RVs take a value of 1, which is equal to the product of the parameters if they are independent, and some other number that might be given otherwise.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).